# mysqldump error 1728 when executing backup bat automatically

Tags: mysql, windows, batch-file

I'm using a bat [script](https://www.redolive.com/utah-web-designers-blog/automated-mysql-backup-for-windows/) to backup a list of databases automatically everyday using Task Scheduler in Windows. However when running the script I run into errors. At this point, the script is supposed to dump over 60 databases but only the first two get dumped. Please see `dumperrors.txt` below for errors. Any help is welcome and appreciated. Thanks!

**mysqlbackup.bat**

```
:: FILE HISTORY ----------------------------------------------
:: UPDATE 11.7.2012  Added setup all folder paths into variables at the top of the script to ease deployment
:: UPDATE 7.16.2012  Added --routines, fix for dashes in filename, and fix for regional time settings
:: UPDATE 3.30.2012  Added error logging to help troubleshoot databases backup errors.   --log-error="c:\MySQLBackups\backupfiles\dumperrors.txt"
:: UPDATE 12.29.2011 Added time bug fix and remote FTP options - Thanks to Kamil Tomas 
:: UPDATE 5.09.2011  v 1.0 


:: If the time is less than two digits insert a zero so there is no space to break the filename

:: If you have any regional date/time issues call this include: getdate.cmd  credit: Simon Sheppard for this cmd - untested
:: call getdate.cmd

set year=%DATE:~10,4%
set day=%DATE:~7,2%
set mnt=%DATE:~4,2%
set hr=%TIME:~0,2%
set min=%TIME:~3,2%

IF %day% LSS 10 SET day=0%day:~1,1%
IF %mnt% LSS 10 SET mnt=0%mnt:~1,1%
IF %hr% LSS 10 SET hr=0%hr:~1,1%
IF %min% LSS 10 SET min=0%min:~1,1%

set backuptime=%year%-%day%-%mnt%-%hr%-%min%
echo %backuptime%



:: SETTINGS AND PATHS 
:: Note: Do not put spaces before the equal signs or variables will fail

:: Name of the database user with rights to all tables
set dbuser=user

:: Password for the database user
set dbpass=password

:: Error log path - Important in debugging your issues
set errorLogPath="C:\MySQLBackups\backupfiles\dumperrors.txt"

:: MySQL EXE Path
set mysqldumpexe="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqldump.exe"

:: Error log path
set backupfldr=C:\MySQLBackups\backupfiles\

:: Path to data folder which may differ from install dir
set datafldr="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\data"

:: Path to zip executable
set zipper="C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe"

:: Number of days to retain .zip backup files 
set retaindays=5

:: DONE WITH SETTINGS



:: GO FORTH AND BACKUP EVERYTHING!

:: Switch to the data directory to enumerate the folders
pushd %datafldr%

echo "Pass each name to mysqldump.exe and output an individual .sql file for each"

:: Thanks to Radek Dolezel for adding the support for dashes in the db name
:: Added --routines thanks for the suggestion Angel

:: turn on if you are debugging
@echo off

FOR /D %%F IN (*) DO (

IF NOT [%%F]==[performance_schema] (
SET %%F=!%%F:@002d=-!
%mysqldumpexe% --user=%dbuser% --password=%dbpass% --databases --routines --log-error=%errorLogPath% %%F > "%backupfldr%%%F.%backuptime%.sql"
) ELSE (
echo Skipping DB backup for performance_schema
)
)

echo "Zipping all files ending in .sql in the folder"


:: .zip option clean but not as compressed
%zipper% a -tzip "%backupfldr%FullBackup.%backuptime%.zip" "%backupfldr%*.sql"


echo "Deleting all the files ending in .sql only"

del "%backupfldr%*.sql"

echo "Deleting zip files older than 30 days now"
Forfiles -p %backupfldr% -s -m *.* -d -%retaindays% -c "cmd /c del /q @path"


::FOR THOSE WHO WISH TO FTP YOUR FILE UNCOMMENT THESE LINES AND UPDATE - Thanks Kamil for this addition!

::cd\[path to directory where your file is saved]
::@echo off
::echo user [here comes your ftp username]>ftpup.dat
::echo [here comes ftp password]>>ftpup.dat
::echo [optional line; you can put "cd" command to navigate through the folders on the ftp server; eg. cd\folder1\folder2]>>ftpup.dat
::echo binary>>ftpup.dat
::echo put [file name comes here; eg. FullBackup.%backuptime%.zip]>>ftpup.dat
::echo quit>>ftpup.dat
::ftp -n -s:ftpup.dat [insert ftp server here; eg. myserver.com]
::del ftpup.dat

echo "done"

::return to the main script dir on end
popd
```

After running the script I get following errors

**dumperrors.txt**

```
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'SHOW FUNCTION STATUS WHERE Db = 'mysql'': Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted (1728)
mysqldump: Got error: 1728: Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted when using LOCK TABLES
```

Comment: What do you think you are trying to do with this code: `SET %%F=!%%F:@002d=-!`

Comment: @Squashman: Im trying to dump all databases into separate files using bat file.

Comment: that does not explain the code I cited.

Comment: @Squashman: Should I remove it? Maybe it's useless?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest that the `errors` file is being overwritten by each error-report.

Try changing

```
--log-error=%errorLogPath%
```

to

```
--log-error=%errorLogPath%.%%F
```

Note that this parameter is *followed* by `%%F` which is the database name.

This change should create an individual error file for each database (if there is an error) with the database name appended to the `.txt`

Comment: [They](http://webcheatsheet.com/sql/Fix_Cannot_load_from_mysql.proc._The_table_is_probably_corrupted.php) suggest to add this line `mysql_upgrade` but I have no idea where in the script I should put it. Any idea?

Comment: That suggestion is a fix for the `1728` problem. You appeared to ask about how to get over the (apparent) short-report on the errors. I would suggest that executing the `mysql_upgrade` line directly before the `mysqldump` within the `for` loop is probably the way to go. Just set up `mysqlupgradeexe` similarly to how `mysqldumpexe` is established and execute `%mysqlupgrade%...` with the appropriate parameters. Test on a copy of a mix of good and "corrupt" databases first - to check.

Comment: Thanks for your second answer that is exactly what Im looking for right now I cant dump the databases with the script because of that error. The only databases I see in the backup folder is mysql and sys.

Comment: I added this line before MySQL EXE
`:: MySQL UPGRADE Path
set mysqlupgradeexe="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysql_upgrade.exe"`

And in the for loop I added this
`%mysqldumpexe% %mysqlupgradeexe% --user=%dbuser% --password=%dbpass% --databases --routines --log-error=%errorLogPath%.%%F` Im seeing new activities. I feel like we're going somewhere. Any new suggestions?